# Problem with two div droppables when drag element (Jquery Ui)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem with Jquery Ui Droppable.

I have two div droppables inside a div container, when i select the violet box and I drag it first to the second div and then to the first one, the div container gets selected together with the first div, this is the error I have, in the JsFiddle a red color gets turned on around it when I’m on top of it. I’ve looked around on the internet but i can’t find a solution.
If I drag the violet box to the first div and then to the second one it works ok, but not the other way around.
I attached a picture
In the JsFiddle the error is shown
Thank you

JsFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/7unvxgqo/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$("#draggable2").draggable({
    // opacity : 0.7, 
    helper: "clone",
    scope: 1,
    start: function (e, ui) {
        $(ui.helper).addClass("drag-helper");

        //console.log(ui);
    }
});


$(".draggable3").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    scope: 1


});


$("#droppable").droppable({
    //Over
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'pointer',

    scope: 1
})

});
```

Image:

[The border red is active when drag a element in first div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxSPW.jpg)

Comment: After a quick google search, I see this is an unfixed known bug. Check this: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9389 - I tried updating your fiddle with the fix found there, but probably due to newer version of jQuery I couldn't get it to work

Comment: thanks for your comment but i not found the solution in that link

Comment: Check this two links from that page: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9337 and http://jsfiddle.net/fvjF4/

Comment: The version of jqueryUi of that example of jsfiddle is older and that code not works with new version of jqueryUi

Comment: I changed the version of my project but not work correctly, some times when i hover the div droppable with drag element the class hover not working

Comment: Cleaned up the fiddle and applied jquery 3.3.1 and ui 1.12.1, still see the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/aL32ru7d/3/ Reading through the two bugs, it seems it comes down to the `out`, but not seeing a solid fix yet.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i saw your JsFiddle and the error is when i hover with the drag box in second div and then in first div, in this moment actived the class of div container (border red).

Answer (score 0):

One work around might be to add a small margin between the two nested elements.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/aL32ru7d/16/

**HTML**

```
<div id="draggable2" class="draggable">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="drop-1" class="drop-zone">
    <p>Drop here</p>
    <div id="drop-nest-1" class="drop-nest">
      <p>First Div</p>
    </div>
    <div id="drop-nest-2" class="drop-nest">
      <p>Second Div</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.drop-nest {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0066CC;
  border: 2px solid #00FF00;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

#draggable2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #CC33CC;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.drop-zone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: #777;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.drag-helper {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  background-color: #CC33CC;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.my-hover {
  border: 5px dashed #FF0000 !important;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#draggable2").draggable({
    // opacity : 0.7, 
    helper: "clone",
    scope: 1,
    start: function(e, ui) {
      $(ui.helper).addClass("drag-helper");
    }
  });

  $(".drop-zone, .drop-nest").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    scope: 1,
    over: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).addClass("my-hover");
    },
    out: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).removeClass("my-hover");
    }
  });
});
```

The issue seems to be related to the `greedy` option and `out`. For a split second, the mouse position triggers both to detect an `over`. Making a little space can allow the mouse to pick one of the elements and not both. The caveat here is that if the mouse is moved very quickly, it can still trigger the issue.

I selected `6px` but I tested with a number of values. The smaller the gap, the easier it is to trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes, if the mouse moved quickly appear the problem